# Sorting an array in MIPS with stack pointer

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I want to sort a pre-defined array with a swap function in MIPS Assembly
but i am stuck at writing a swap code.

Also i must use stack pointer.

this is the c++ code for it:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i+=1) {
    for (j=i-1; j>=0 && v[j] > v[j+1]; j-=1) {
    swap (v,j);
    }
}
```

this is the code. i've tried using jal and jr and messed up.

```
.data
.align 2
ARRAY: .word 12, 4, 23, 2, 5, 26, 13, 42, 41, 18
msg1: .asciiz " "

.text
.globl main
main:
la $a0, ARRAY
addi $a1, $zero, 10     #array length

sort:
addi $sp, $sp, -20
sw $ra, 16($sp)
sw $s3, 12($sp)
sw $s2, 8($sp)
sw $s1, 4($sp)
sw $s0, 0($sp)

add $s0, $zero, $zero
add $s2, $a0, $zero
add $s3, $a1, $zero

loop1:
slt $t0, $s0, $s3
beq $t0, $zero, exit1
addi $s1, $s0, -1

loop2:
slt $t0, $s1, $zero
bne $t0, $zero, exit2
sll $t1, $s1, 2
add $t2, $s2, $t1
lw $t3, 0($t2)
lw $t4, 4($t2)
slt $t0, $t4, $t3
beq $t0, $zero, exit2

add $a0, $s2, $zero
add $a1, $s3, $zero

swap:
?

addi $s1, $s1, -1
j loop2

exit2:
addi $s0, $s0, 1
j loop1

exit1:
lw $s0, 0($sp)
lw $s1, 4($sp)
lw $s2, 8($sp)
lw $s3, 12($sp)
lw $ra, 16($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 20

exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

what do i need to do in order to swap the lesser one with greater one so i can sort the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not implement loops as you do, with the test at the entrance of the loop. You need an extra branch that is less efficient and makes code difficult to understand.

If you have a loop

```
for(initial; test; increment) { body }
```

Just translate it to:

```
   initial
loop:
   body
   increment
   test -> loop
```

You only need a unique branch and this largely improves code readability.

Also, start by writing a C code with pointers to ease the translation

```
for (i=0; i<n; i+=1) {
    for (j=i-1, parray=array[i-1]; j>=0 ; j-=1, parray--) {
       if(*parray > *(parray+1)) 
         swap (parray); // the pointer is sufficient
    }
}
```

Concerning the swap operation, why do you want a subprogram? You have stored the values of array[j] and array[j+1] in registers, and you just have to write them back in their proper positions.

Here is a possible transation (skipping the start and end that remain unchanged)

```
...
sort:
addi $sp, $sp, -20
sw $ra, 16($sp)
sw $s3, 12($sp)
sw $s2, 8($sp)
sw $s1, 4($sp)
sw $s0, 0($sp)

   add $s0, $zero, $zero # i=0
   add $s2, $a0, $zero   # @array
   add $s3, $a1, $zero   # N

loop1:
    addi $s1, $s0, -1    # j=i-1
    sll $t1, $s1, 2
    add $t2, $s2, $t1    # @array[j]

loop2:
    lw $t3, 0($t2)         # $t3 array[j]
    lw $t4, 4($t2)         # $t4 array[j+1]
    sgt $t0, $t3, $t4      # array[j] > array[j+1]?
    bne $t0, $zero, noswap # no? -> noswap

swap:
    # just exchange the loaded values of array[j] and array[j+1]
    sw $t3, 4($t2)
    sw $t4, 0($t2)

noswap:

    addi $s1, $s1, -1   # j--
    addi $t2, $t2, -4   # array--
    sge $t0, $s1, $zero # j>=0?
    bne $t0, $zero, loop2

    addi $s0, $s0, 1  #i++
    slt $t0, $s0, $s3 #i<N?
    bne $t0, $zero, loop1

exit1:
...
```

The number of loads may be reduced, as in every iteration you already have array[i] already loaded.